# Stuck in choosing stock photo

Tags: photography

I don't have a lot of experience, I was ask a super specific thing to deliver with stock images. I am failing to find it, am I just using the wrong keywords, searching in the wrong place?
Or is it really too specific?
Word of advice please.

Comment: If you're failing to find it, it's time to edit the most relevant image you could find (as explained in the answer). And make some compromises. I hooe the client would understand it.

Comment: Welcome Dotcomma102!!  Just on the surface.... How would anyone here know if you are "using the wrong keywords"? You don't detail the keywords you *are* using.

Comment: Could you not employ a photographer, or take one yourself? Or find an image that is close, but manipulate it, and replace the background.  While there may be millions of stock photos out there, once you start limiting your choices too much, then naturally you reduce your chances of finding one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sound like you are drowning in a glass of water.

This site is not for "giving me advice" but for specific "problem-solving" questions. I mention this because our wording of your requirements is also "disperse".

What is having fun? You have to be more specific, Are they playing ball at the beach? Are they indoors watching TV, or a video game?

What is a neutral background? Gray color? You can do that in Photoshop. Blurred or out of focus? Do that in Photoshop. Not a kitchen, not a bedroom, but a living room that is better wording than neutral.

Enough space for vectors? Why does the search engine need to know that? How could anyone know? Space where? Did you find the specific photo but turn it does not have "enough space" to the right? Be creative and do something on the right. Edit the image with a similar texture, copy, paste, clone, stretch, invert, paint, blur, smudge.

What race? No, you will probably not find specific photos of Eskimo people using traditional clothing and having fun on California beaches. Stock photography is in fact limited on what the photographers can have at reach to photograph and imagine what other people would need.

---

But you can use images generated by artificial intelligence like Midjourney or OpenAI, where you can even put a base scene as a reference. But to get a specific image you need a lot of trial and error...

I got this... I also needed different wording...

[image]